# Azure Function - Using logging to log into file and return the file contents in response to http request?

Tags: azure, function, azure-devops, azure-functions

I need to write an azure function in python (http based trigger).
(Note - Function is running as zip deployment from blob storage.)

Function should use logging to log messages , errors and warning to specific log file.

In the last i want to read this log file and return it as httpd.response ?

```
Here is my code.

import os
import os.path
import azure.functions as func
import logging as cslog
import random
import time

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="HttpTrigger1")
@app.route(route="hello")
def test_function(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    log_file = os.path.join(os.environ['TMP'], str(random.randint(1, 100)) + ".app.log")

    cslog.basicConfig(filename=log_file, filemode='w',
                      format='%(asctime)s - %(process)d - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')

    cslog.warning('No1. This will get logged to a file')
    cslog.warning('No2. This will get logged to a file')
    cslog.warning('No3. This will get logged to a file')
    cslog.warning('No4. This will get logged to a file')
    cslog.info(os.getcwd())
    check_file = os.path.isfile(log_file)
    cslog.info(check_file)

    with open(log_file) as f:
        content_text = "\n"
        content = f.readlines()
        for line in content:
            content_text = content_text + str(line)

    return func.HttpResponse(content_text)
```

When i run function it gives me error that log file does not exist ? Why it is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

> When i run function it gives me error that log file does not exist ? Why it is happening?

The error occurs when the function code could not find the log file in your directory to write logs into it. You can create a log File manually inside your function zip folder or dynamically in your function code write the logs into that file and return the file content in the HTTP Response with the code  below:-

**My init.py:-**

```py
import os
import azure.functions as func
import logging as cslog

# app = func.FunctionApp()

# @app.function_name(name="HttpTrigger1")
# @app.route(route="hello")
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    log_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "app.log")

    cslog.basicConfig(filename=log_file, filemode='a',
                      format='%(asctime)s - %(process)d - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')

    cslog.warning('No1. This will get logged to a file')
    cslog.warning('No2. This will get logged to a file')
    cslog.warning('No3. This will get logged to a file')
    cslog.warning('No4. This will get logged to a file')

    try:
        with open(log_file, mode='a') as f:
            f.write('No1. This will get logged to a file\n')
            f.write('No2. This will get logged to a file\n')
            f.write('No3. This will get logged to a file\n')
            f.write('No4. This will get logged to a file\n')
    except Exception as e:
        cslog.error(f"Error writing to log file: {str(e)}")

    try:
        with open(log_file) as f:
            content_text = "\n"
            content = f.readlines()
            for line in content:
                content_text = content_text + str(line)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        content_text = "Log file not found"

    return func.HttpResponse(content_text)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Browser HTTP Response:-**

[image]

**app.log file content:-**

[image]